# Retrieving image stored in storage folder

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-5.3

Using laravel 5.3, I am trying to retrieve an image in a view. How I could do this?
folder structure: storage/app/avatard

Here is the code:

```
public function storeAvatar(Request $request, $username)
{
  $user = User::where('name', $username)->first();
  $avatar = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');

  $avatar = explode('avatars/', $avatar);



  $user->user_setting()->updateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => $user->id],
    ['avatar' => $avatar[1]]
  );

  return back();
}
```

This is how the image path is saved in the database:

> /users/avatar/default.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat like this you can achieve as storage path is directly unavailable for public. you need to provide public url in route like this.

In view

```
<img src="{{route('avatar',$filename)}}" />
```

or

```
<img src="/avatars/{{$filename}}" />
```

In routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/avatars/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path() . '/avatars/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
})->name('avatar');
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me even tho i did `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 6):

First create a storage link by typing in

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and then

```
<img src={{ asset('storage/folder_name/image_name') }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you store your files in the `storage/app/public` directory as per the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk) you can create a symbolic link on Unix/Linux systems that will allow you to reference the files as if they were in the `public` directory.

Create the symbolic link using the artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

In your views you are then able to reference the files using

```
{{ asset('storage/path/to/file.png') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider if you are using Homestead, you must create the symbolic link from the virtual machine;

In your terminal:

```
homestead ssh
```

go to your project folder:

```
cd Code/YOUR_PROJECT
```

now you can execute the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```