# Why do I not get images from the storage folder from a friend

Tags: database, laravel, storage

So, me and a friend are working on the same laravel project and we store images in the database and in storage/public/cover_images but when he git pulled he did not get the images. We think it is because of the link :

```html
<div class="bookCover">                                  
  <img src="/storage/public/cover_images/{{ $book->image }}" 
       style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
</div>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you mean his project does not contain the images or that he cannot access the images?

Comment: When I upload a book with a cover page he does not see and when he does I do not see his images.

Comment: Your case is very unclear, please expand your question with information about what exactly you are doing with every step what is happening. The question is very unclear as it is now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving image stored in storage folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138642/retrieving-image-stored-in-storage-folder)

Comment: So the pictures you can see are mine but the one that cant be seen is his. 
http://prntscr.com/lti44w

Comment: It seems your question is too general. Add some information so others can answer. I think it is impossible to find a solution for you with the information you gave

Comment: You should clearify in your question the following topics: 
1. Do you commit the images to your repository?
2. Do you also dump your database, commit it to your repo and your friend imports it?

Comment: No, images are not being pushed to GIT. I git push and then he git pulls.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `.gitignore` file on your `storage/` folder and in your friend's `storage/` folder to, that worked for me.

Comment: What job it does? I mean, if I do it, is it going to screw something else afterwards?

Comment: If you create a file in your repository named .gitignore, Git uses it to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit. But if you wanna test it just cut and paste it on your desktop and do the commit again. You will see the storage folder commited in your online repository.

Comment: Yes, but I read that it should stay in the project for security reasons.

Comment: @JoJo you are not deleting the `.gitignore` file from your project your are just telling git to include this folder when committing, because the storage folder is usually a heavy folder they recommend to omitting it, but in your case you want to include it, same as me. There still a global config file in user home directory, `~/.gitignore.`