# How to display images from storage folder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve images from storage to the view, but it doesn't show the image, in the console I see this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I have tried many solutions, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138642/retrieving-image-stored-in-storage-folder/41138726) but it's still not working.

**Controller**

```php
 class productController extends Controller
 {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
    $userId = $request->user()->id;
    $products = product::where('admin', $userId)->get();
   return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
  }

  public function admin()
  {
   $products=product::all();
   return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
   }



  public function show($id)
 {
  $product = ProductsPhoto::findOrFail($id);
  return view('productsPhoto.show', compact('product'));

  }
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function store(Request $request) 
  { 

    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
      }
```

ProductsPhotos.php

```
  class ProductsPhoto extends Model
  {
  protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'filename'];

   public function product()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

Product.php

```
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable=['name','price','info','image','stock'];
```

**Blade**

```php
 @foreach($products as $product)
     <img src="{{ asset('storage/photos/filename') }}"
 @endforeach
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show where the photos path in your folder. thank you

Comment: Photo path looks like this /Users/Dev/storage/app/photos/5LJYSo3xp7n1jJbhjz112mytrN1XQYvK2ZqFcYd7.jpeg   @Jovs

Answer (score 0):

Run this artisan command `php artisan storage:link`. In Blade, use Storage facade below :

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
     <img src="{{ \Storage::url($products->productPhoto->filename) }}"
 @endforeach
```

/* UPDATE */

```
 public function index(Request $request)
 {
    $products = product::where('admin', \Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
   return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
  }
```

Comment: I tried that before and got this error `"Undefined variable: $filename` @ivan

Comment: Update answer to get $filename variable.

Comment: Do I need any route for that show($id)? because I put that show($id) above the store function but still not working. @ivan

Comment: Show me your controller

Comment: Please check question updates  for controller @Ivan

Comment: Where blade you want to display images ? Index or admin ? And model Product and ProductPhoto have any relationship ?

Comment: I want it to show in the index, models works fine, they have relationship  @Ivan

Comment: update my answer, Please note I think `productPhoto` is a relationship between Product model and ProductPhoto model, edit it if I wrong.

Comment: `productPhoto` belongs to product model that is the relationship@Ivan

Comment: Because productPhoto is not relationship, show me 2 model Product and ProductPhoto

Comment: I see your Product model not relationship with ProductPhoto. Add below to your Product model : `public function productPhoto()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPhoto');
    }`

Comment: It keeps throwing an error `Property [ProductsPhotos] does not exist on this collection instance.` @Ivan

Comment: `productPhoto` not `productPhotos`

Comment: I have tried both, `productPhoto`  and `ProductPhotos`. Still not working

Comment: the model name is ProductsPhotos but the relationship is productPhoto, see my comment above.

Comment: oh my bad, the model is `productsPhoto`