# Images not displaying in the web page(PHP with Laravel), other code is working 100% fine

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

My code is working fine and showing the contents stored in the database. But not showing images which are stored in: C:\xampp\htdocs\Task_List\storage\app\fileToUpload

DisplayDataController.php

```
class DisplayDataController extends BaseController
{
public function displaydata()
{

    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','email','password','pic')->get();
    return view('displaydata',['users'=> $users]);
}
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'DisplayDataController@displaydata' );
```

displaydata.blade.php

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            Display Data
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <fieldset>

    <legend>User Records</legend>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>        
            <th>Image</th>        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($users as  $user)
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->password}}</td>
            <td>
           <!-- <img src="{{ url('storage/app/fileToUpload/'.$user->pic) }}" style="height:100; width:100" />; -->


           <img src="{{ url('storage/app/fileToUpload')}}{{$user->pic}}" style="height:100; width:100" /> 

            </td>
            </tr>        
        @endforeach
    <input type="hidden" value={{csrf_token()}} name=_token>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Only issue with:

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/app/fileToUpload')}}{{$user->pic}}" style="height:100; width:100" />
```

Comment: check this answer. storage directory is not accessible directly. use a route to return the file response for the images stored in storage folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138726/1409707

Comment: @aimme in my db images are stored as:  
fileToUpload/1pZn1fwL0pldyfgvDPT4giLPkb662OL5B3kjs.jpeg

Comment: if so my answer will work. just need to remove fileToUpload prefix from string. editing the answer.

Comment: i have edited my answer to make it work as you have stored with prefix. but it's better to remove the prefix part from db and add it to file prefix on code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create symbolic link by running this in command prompt

```
php artisan storage:link
```

therefore to access in blade like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$user->pic)}}" style="height:100; width:100" />
```

read here for more details [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Already worked with it. Not working @Ghiffari

Comment: In my db images are stored as:
 
fileToUpload/1pZn1fwL0pldyfgvDPT4giLPkb662OL5B3kjs.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/app/fileToUpload/'.$user->pic)}}" style="height:100; width:100" />
```

Comment: change the , into . ( . $user->pic )

Comment: @zahid its is not working

Comment: not working too @GhiffariAssamar

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat like this you can achieve as storage path is directly unavailable for public. you need to provide public url in route like this.

In view

```
<img src="{{route('images.show',$user->pic)}}" />
```

or

```
<img src="/images/{{$user->pic}}" />
```

In routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/images/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path() . '/app/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
})->name('images.show');
```